# Sort menu items alphabetically

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to sort these menu's alphabetically. Menu lists are in a CMS that are tough to organize so just decided to do it with jQuery. I found some source code but it creates each menu to show the whole list of 20+ items in each dropdown vs sorting them into their respected parent dropdowns.

```js
var mylist = $('.dropdown-menu');
var listitems = mylist.children('a').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class=" dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item 1" href="/donate_today">Donate</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/ways_to_give">Ways To Give</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/planned_giving_a_legacy_of_love">Legacy of Love</a>   
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/paypal">Paypal</a> 
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item 1" href="/adopt">Adopt</a>     
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/adopt_today">Adoption Process</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/alumni">Alumni</a>   
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/adoptable_animals">Adoptable Animals</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/resources">Resources</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/foster_to_adopt">Foster To Adopt</a>   
    </div>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a helper function `sortItems` which will sort items in a single list and the invoke it on each list individually (via `$('.dropdown-menu').each(sortItems);` ).

The `sortItems` function finds all `<a>` items, sorts them alphabetically and then reinserts them back into the list in correct order.

```js
function sortItems(index, menu){
  const listItems = $(menu).children('a').get();
  listItems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
  });
  $(menu).append(listItems);
}

$('.dropdown-menu').each(sortItems);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class=" dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item 1" href="/donate_today">Donate</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/ways_to_give">Ways To Give</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/planned_giving_a_legacy_of_love">Legacy of Love</a>   
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/paypal">Paypal</a> 
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item 1" href="/adopt">Adopt</a>     
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/adopt_today">Adoption Process</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/alumni">Alumni</a>   
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/adoptable_animals">Adoptable Animals</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/resources">Resources</a>    
      <a class="dropdown-item 2" href="/foster_to_adopt">Foster To Adopt</a>   
    </div>
  </li>
```